# Search Pastbin.com with Mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

Here is the code I have borrowed so far works great on Google.com but not on pastebin.com would love some input on why I can not search pastebin.com

```
import re
from mechanize import Browser
br = Browser()

# Ignore robots.txt
br.set_handle_robots( False )
# user-agent that isn't a robot
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

# Retrieve the web page
br.open( "http://pastebin.com" )

# Select the search box and search for 'foo'
br.select_form( 'f' )
br.form[ 'q' ] = 'facebook'

# Get the search results
br.submit()

# Find the link
resp = None
for link in br.links():
    siteMatch = re.compile( 'www.facebook.com' ).search( link.url )
    if siteMatch:
        resp = br.follow_link( link )
        break

# Print the site
content = resp.get_data()
print content
```

Comment: What does it mean you cannot search? Any errors?

Comment: File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'f'

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like seeing what pastebine is sending your script? You're simply assuming nothing could ever go wrong.

Comment: but on google this script works fine.  I want to log into pastebin.com and then using "q" use the search box to define my search and get the results on google this works

Comment: But Pastebin is not Google. What makes you think they would have everything named the same way?

Answer (score 0):

```
br.select_form( 'f' )
br.form[ 'q' ] = 'facebook'
```

There is no form on the Pastebin home page called "f". Read the source to the page to find the correct names.

Comment: `q` is actually the name of the search field box - the OP got lucky here.

Comment: Oops! Mixed up the class and name. So that part's right, but only by accident.

Comment: thanks for the help and suggestions the br.select_form( 'f' )
br.form[ 'q' ] = 'facebook' should be

Comment: br.select_form(name='search_form') and br.form[ 'q' ] = 'facebook'

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing can be solved by providing a valid form name:

```
br.select_form(name='search_form')
```

And, you will have problems later, while trying to grab the results - but this is a part of a different question.

Comment: this appeared to work but now the issue of grabbing the results thanks for the help I will continue to plug away for now.